# Deployment Of Winform Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I tried to deploy a WinForms project in which I am using a resource file. I tried publish method for deployment. It builds properly but when I tried to run the application is giving me the error "Resource file not found Error". This error message I have customized in my application.
My question is, how to add a resource file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on resource file, click on `Properties` and set its build action to `Embedded Resource`

Comment: Hey, but where will I get that resouce file? Is this the proper path: Solution explorer--> GUI(proj name)--> propeties-->RESOURCES-->add resource-->

Comment: yes, that's right. once added, you can use above steps mentioned by Adeel.

Comment: I used the option and set it's build action to Embedded Resource
... but after publishing still showing same error. Resource file not found...what to do??

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Namesapce. That should match.

Comment: Are you sure this shouldn't be a comment?